# Trying to create a dropdown menu where header changes height on drop down

Tags: html, css, button, drop-down-menu, header

I'm trying to create a header which changes height when you hover over the "Language" button

You can view the full demo of the header [here.](http://cssdeck.com/labs/dcnh429n)

This is how it looks like before you click on the "Language" button:

[image: Before click on language button]

This is what I want the dropdown menu to look like when you click on the "Language" button:

[image: After click on language button]

Basically the header looks exactly the same as the images as you can see in the demo, the only thing i'm having hard time with is the dropdown menu, although i've created the dropdown menu, but i'm not sure how i can make it fit like the image above. I've tried many different things, but i can't seem to find out how i can make it like the image.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is with javascript if you want it to be a toggle button. As for getting it below the navbar all you have to do is put it inside the language div then toggle an id or a class onto the div then change the style of the dropdown to show.

Comment: it's not possible without using javascript?

Comment: @Nohman if you only use css it is much harder and has less support though to simulate click events using css have a look at this: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSSClickEvents/index.html Also whats so bad with javascript

Comment: I dont know javascript yet, that's the problem. I think i'll have to dive into javascript courses soon then